# Polymorphic user model when using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, polymorphic-associations, polymorphism

I am building a job board and therefore have two user models and employer and an applicant.
I am using devise and therefore my challenge now is to use this with the polymorphic relationship.

Through some rails console testing I know that (resource) in devise passes all the user information and it is passing the role_type which is either applicant or employer. However it is set to nil and therefore although my user is being saved it is not saving the role type of applicant or employer. Furthermore nothing is being saved in the applicant or employer tables just in the user table. My code is below but my question really is how do I pass the role_type to the devise resource hash? Or if this isnt possible the most elegant way of solving this problem.

Many Thanks!

Also the full project code is here if I have missed anything https://github.com/PatGW/jobs

Below is the views->devise->user->new.html.erb

```
<h1>Sign Up</h1>

 <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
        <h2> Form is invalid</h2>
        <ul>
            <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= radio_button_tag :role_type, "employer", :checked => false %><br />
    <%= label :role_type, 'Employer' %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= radio_button_tag :role_type, "applicant", :checked => true %><br />
    <%= label :role_type, 'Applicant' %>
</p>


<p class="button"><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

UsersController which inherits from DeviseController

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def new
super
 end

def create
 User.transaction do
  super
  after_sign_in_path(resource)
 end
end

private

def after_sign_in_path(resource)
 debugger
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
 if params[:role_type] == "coach"
  role = Employer.create
 else params[:role_type] == "player"
  role = Applicant.create
 end 
 end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not Devise related, but association / OO related. I checked out your code:   Your applicant and employer model seem to HAVE a user field, while those models should actually inherit from user, for they ARE a kind of user. So, try this:

```
class Employer < User
  attr_accessible :location, :logo, :name
end
```

for starters, and see if it helps. (Btw: Obviously, you should also change the code for applicant)

Comment: Hi Stobbej, gave that a try but it doesn't help. I have had a play around using rails debugger and I can see that the role_type parameter isnt being passed in the devise resource and not being saved upon calling the create method. Bit stumped any ideas?